How to view Cristal Reports files
How can I view a report created in Cristal Reports. Is there an open source alternative to view .rpt files and export to PDF or XLS formats. I've researched a few open source viewers, but I don't know of any, only paid options, which makes it unfeasible for programmers who can't afford it.
